# How do I execute script using crontab

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I have a script inside a folder path `/home/rohit/Report/test.sh`
I want to run this script using `crontab` every 5 minutes

I opened terminal any type these command

```
crontab -e
```

write this line in crontab

```
5 * * * * rohit /home/rohit/Report/test.sh
```

save and exit.

but It does not execute script.

Am I doing anything wrong.

my `test.sh` is

```
ruby file1.rb
ruby file2.rb
```

file1.rb and file2.rb are also present in that folder

Comment: Try using the full path to `ruby`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead,

```
*/5 * * * * /home/rohit/Report/test.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to manage your cron jobs.